# Upper bound of a quadratic, given the upper bound of variable

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, quadratics

Problem: Let $p(x)$ be a quadratic polynomial $p(x)$ = $ax^2+bx+c$ such that $|p(x)|$ $≤$ $1$ for |$x$| $≤$ $1$.
Prove that

$|cx^2+bx+a|$ $≤$ $2$ for |$x$| $≤$ $1$. (Source: Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics, Page 201, Problem 16)

My attempt: I tried $|cx^2+bx+a|$ $≤$ |$a+b+c$| = $|p(1)|$ for $|x|$ $≤$ 1, but after that it gets complicated. More specifically, the upper bound for the quadratic asked actually comes out to be $|p(1)|$ $≤$ 1, and so the given statement is proved. However I'm thrown off by why the problem states $≤$ $2$ and not $1$.

Any hints would be appreciated, but please don't post a definite solution. In the case I solve it using the hints given, I'll post my own answer below. If I cannot, I'll edit this question asking for a solution.

Comment: I'm suspicious of $|cx^2+bx+a|\le|a+b+c|$ for $|x|\le1$. For one thing, some of those coefficients could be negative. Or $p(0)$ could be zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, my bad. I didn't notice both of your points, I'll try it again, perhaps I can get it right this time.

Comment: @GerryMyerson on another note, $|cx^2+bx+a|$ ≤  |c|+|b|+|a| for |x| <=1. Could this help?

Comment: True, so now the question is whether you can find a useful bound for $|a|+|b|+|c|$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan sorry about that, it was a typo I didn't notice; will fix it. I don't think it changes the condition much though, right?(Since the range of x includes +1 and -1 too)

Comment: @amar06 No worries. You're right that it doesn't really change anything, which is why I stated it was a minor point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employing a rather common strategy for such problems, from $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, we get $c=p(0), b = \frac12\left[p(1)-p(-1)\right]$ and $a = \frac12\left[p(1)+p(-1)\right]-p(0)$.

Hence with $q(x) = cx^2+bx+a$, we get
$$q(x) = p(0)x^2+\tfrac12\left[p(1) - p(-1)\right]x +\tfrac12\left[p(1)+p(-1)\right]-p(0)$$
$$\qquad = p(0)(x^2-1)+\tfrac12p(1)(x+1)-\tfrac12p(-1)(x-1)$$
$$\implies |q(x)| \leqslant |p(0)||x^2-1|+\tfrac12|p(1)||x+1|+\tfrac12|p(-1)||x-1|$$
$$\qquad \leqslant (1-x^2)+\tfrac12(1+x)+\tfrac12(1-x)=2-x^2\leqslant 2$$

--
P.S.  Take $p(x)=2x^2-1$ and you will notice this bound is tight.

Comment: That's the exact kind of solution I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Define the class of quadratic polynomials P2 whose members having sum of all abs coefficients being less than or equal to 1:
P2={p(x)=ax^2 +bx+c |  |a|+|b|+|c|<=1}

Show that

1. If p(x) ε P2 then |p(x)|<=1 for all |x|<=1

Proof

|p(x)|<= |a||x|^2+|b| |x|+ |c|<= |a|+|b|+|c|<=1 for all |x|<=1

2. If p ε P2 then q ε P2 where q(x)= cx^2 + bx +a then q ε P2

Proof

|q(x)|<= |c||x|^2 + |b| |x|+ |a|<= |c|+|b|+|a| <= 1 for all |x|<=1

It follows that |q(x)| <=2 for all |x| <=1

QED

Comment: $|r(x)|$ ≤ 1 + $|q(x)|$ and $|q(x)|$ ≤ $|c-a|$+$|a-c|$ is understood, but I couldn't understand why |q(x)| ≤ 1. If it is said |p(x)| = $|ax^2+bx+c|$ ≤ 1 for |x| ≤ 1, won't it be true only for co-efficients a,b,c? Because if they were to be true for all such co-efficients then one could find a set of (a,b,c), one of the coefficients sufficiently large such that |q(x)| >=1.